# how to set height only when resizing using ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

The following code resizes an image so that its width is 200 and its height is whatever...
How would I do it so that the height was 200 and the width was whatever...

$command = MAGICK_PATH."convert ".$filename." -resize 200 ".$filename;
exec($command);

Kind regards J

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) has a complete overview over resizing options.

You are looking for

> `xheight` Height given, width automagically selected to preserve aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can get width and height of the input image and then convert it. I'm not familiar with PHP so I'll post code for bash.

To change size of image to 500x200:

```
convert "$filename" -resize 500x200 "$filename"
```

To change size, while keep width or height old:

```
width=$(identify -format "%w" "$filename")
height=$(identify -format "%h" "$filename")
convert "$filename" -resize "200x$height" "$filename"
```

Note: instead of using

```
convert "$filename" [opts] "$filename"
```

it's better to use

```
mogrify "filename"
```

Comment: Thanks ghostmansd, convert ".$filename." -resize x200 ".$filename; ... i just need a x infront of the dimension to make it to that height rather than the width.... thanks for your time and help.